# ClickOnce program not updating when run

Tags: wpf, ftp, clickonce

I finished my first version of my program and started up an FTP server for publishing it into. It publishes just fine, but the problem is when I run the program I see the updating stuff, but it does not find another update.

My FTP URL seems to be fine, ftp://xxxxx.com/Crafting%20Guide/, but I'm not sure about my *Installation Folder URL* (\Localhost\Program Files\Trove Crafting Guide). I checked the folder and no program is installed there so to be honest I dont know what that one means anymore.

I published the file with a change to see if it would update and if I click the setup.exe again the update will start. But when I click the icon on the desktop nothing happens.

I wanted it to check for updates everytime it runs, where it should check for updates on the FTP server and if any new updates it should update it from the FTP server. I also start thinking that it is the wrong kind of updating tool I'm using.

Do you know a fix for my problem? Do tell or if you know another way to do what I want, tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution made here:

```
private void Update()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = client.OpenRead("<URL>");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

    if (content != Version)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to update?",
                            "Update Found", MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxImage.Information) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            Process.Start("<URL>");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I went off the idea with the FTP server and used my Dropbox account instead.